# Where do I insert code into the header?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I recently updated my Drupal 'Newsflash' theme but one of my javascripts stopped working. I contacted the writer of the js script and he suggested that my head section has lost the markup for importing the overlibmws.js file, and that I should put it back.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/overlib.js"></script>
```

Where do I go in Drupal 7 (Im guessing it is a tpl file) to insert this code into the header?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x) which by default is part of the `system` module. Copy the file to the location of your theme and add your code. The copy should take precedence over the default .tpl file.

Warning: Do not hack the core! I.e. if you add this change directly to the `system` module file it will be overwritten with the next update. In fact even adding the file to the third party theme is not a very clean solution (for the same reasons).

Consider using [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) instead (requires custom code).